# NGXS Ionic storage SQLite

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am trying to implement SQLite in NGXS. I am using the NGXS Storage as defined here: https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/storage.

I have defined my custom storage engine like this:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IonicStorageProvider implements AsyncStorageEngine {
    constructor(private storage: Storage) {}

    length(): Observable<number> {
        return from(this.storage.keys()).lift(keyArray => keyArray.length);
    }

    getItem(key: any): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.storage.get(key));
    }

    setItem(key: any, val: any): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.storage.set( key, val ));
    }

    removeItem(key: any): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.storage.remove(key));
    }

    clear(): Observable<void> {
        return from(this.storage.clear());
    }

    key(val: number): Observable<string> {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }

    keys(): Observable<any> {
        return from(this.storage.keys());
    }
}
```

And defined it in the app.module:

```
    IonicStorageProvider,
    StoragePlugin,
    {
        provide: STORAGE_ENGINE,
        useClass: IonicStorageProvider
    },
    {
        provide: NGXS_STORAGE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS,
        useValue: {
            key: environment.stateStorageKeys,
            serialize: JSON.stringify,
            deserialize: JSON.parse
        }
    },
    {
        provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
        useClass: StoragePlugin,
        multi: true
    }
```

And defined this StoragePlugin which implements the handle function:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxsPlugin, NgxsNextPluginFn, actionMatcher, InitState, UpdateState, getValue, setValue } from '@ngxs/store';
import { tap, concatMap, reduce, map, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of, from, concat } from 'rxjs';
import {
    NGXS_STORAGE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS,
    STORAGE_ENGINE,
    NgxsStoragePluginOptions,
    StorageEngine,
    AsyncStorageEngine,
    AsyncStorageEngineProxy
} from '@ngxs-labs/async-storage-plugin';

@Injectable()
export class StoragePlugin implements NgxsPlugin {
    private asyncStorageEngine: AsyncStorageEngine;

    constructor(
        @Inject(NGXS_STORAGE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS) private pluginOptions: NgxsStoragePluginOptions,
        @Inject(STORAGE_ENGINE) private storageEngine: StorageEngine | AsyncStorageEngine
    ) {
        if (typeof this.storageEngine.length === 'function') {
            this.asyncStorageEngine = this.storageEngine as AsyncStorageEngine;
        } else {
            this.asyncStorageEngine = new AsyncStorageEngineProxy(this.storageEngine as StorageEngine);
        }
    }

    handle(state: any, event: any, next: NgxsNextPluginFn) {
        console.log('StoragePlugin handle');
        const options = this.pluginOptions || {} as any;
        const matches = actionMatcher(event);
        const isInitAction = matches(InitState) || matches(UpdateState);
        const keys: any[] = Array.isArray(options.key) ? options.key : [options.key];
        let hasMigration = false;
        let initAction: Observable<any> = of(state);

        if (isInitAction) {
            console.log('StoragePlugin getItem');
            initAction = from(keys).pipe(
                concatMap(key => this.asyncStorageEngine.getItem(key.key || key).pipe(map(val => [key, val]))),
                reduce((previousState, [key, val]) => {
                    console.log('StoragePlugin: getItem key:', key);
                    console.log('StoragePlugin: getItem val:', val);
                    const isMaster = key === '@@STATE';
                    let nextState = previousState;
                    if (val !== 'undefined' && typeof val !== 'undefined' && val !== null) {
                        try {
                            val = options.deserialize(val);
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.error('Error ocurred while deserializing the store value, falling back to empty object.', e);
                            val = {};
                        }

                        if (options.migrations) {
                            options.migrations.forEach(strategy => {
                                const versionMatch = strategy.version === getValue(val, strategy.versionKey || 'version');
                                const keyMatch = (!strategy.key && isMaster) || strategy.key === key;
                                if (versionMatch && keyMatch) {
                                    val = strategy.migrate(val);
                                    hasMigration = true;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (!isMaster) {
                            nextState = setValue(previousState, key.key || key, val);
                        } else {
                            nextState = { ...previousState, ...val };
                        }
                    }
                    return nextState;
                }, state),
            );
        }

        return initAction.pipe(
            concatMap(stateAfterInit => next(stateAfterInit, event)),
            tap(async nextState => {
                if (!isInitAction || (isInitAction && hasMigration)) {
                    for (let key of keys) {
                        let val = nextState as any;

                        if (key !== '@@STATE') {
                            if (!key || typeof (key) === 'string') {
                                val = await getValue(nextState, key);
                            } else {
                                const subKeys = key.subKeys;
                                key = key.key;
                                val = await getValue(nextState, key);

                                const filtered = [];
                                for (const element of val) {
                                    const obj = {} as any;

                                    for (const subKey of subKeys) {
                                        obj[subKey] = element[subKey];
                                    }

                                    filtered.push(obj);
                                }

                                val = filtered;
                            }
                        }

                        try {
                            console.log('StoragePlugin: setItem key:', key);
                            console.log('StoragePlugin: setItem val:', val);
                            this.asyncStorageEngine.setItem(key, options.serialize(val));
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.error('Error ocurred while serializing the store value, value not updated.', e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        );
    }
```

I have tested the get and set on storage seperately and it's working fine. However when starting the app it first calls the setItem multiple times resetting the state, then calling getItem (which retrieves the resetted state).

I have been using a localstorage plugin before this one and that plugin called getItem first and then setItem which correctly sets the state.

Old Storage Provider:

```
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { AsyncStorageEngine } from '@ngxs-labs/async-storage-plugin';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@capacitor/core';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CapacitorStorageProvider implements AsyncStorageEngine {
    length(): Observable<number> {
        return from(Storage.keys()).lift(keyArray => keyArray.length);
    }

    getItem(key: any): Observable<any> {
        return from(Storage.get({ key: key })).pipe(pluck('value'));
    }

    setItem(key: any, val: any): Observable<any> {
        return from(Storage.set({ key: key, value: val }));
    }

    removeItem(key: any): Observable<any> {
        return from(Storage.remove({ key: key }));
    }

    clear(): Observable<void> {
        return from(Storage.clear());
    }

    key(val: number): Observable<string> {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
}
```